# Schedule GCE instance periodic restart

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a GCE instance running. Is there a way to schedule periodic restart?

I'm asking because I have a memory leak in JVM that I can't solve with out restarting the instance. Right now I restart it manually but it would be nice to automate it.

Comment: I don't know about scheduled instance restart functionality in GCE but you can add a script with restart command to scheduler inside an instance (cron + sudo reboot in case of Linux). Also maybe there is no need to restart whole instance and you can just stop/start your JVM process.

Comment: Thanks but for me killing the process doesn't do the job ---- it reduces the memory usage but it's still high. I am not sure what's the issue, since I am only running one jar on that instance. I suspect it's the web framework I am using is leaky.

Comment: Ok, if restart JVM process is not enough for you (I can not imagine how could it possible but) you can get away with `sudo reboot` in `crontab` to restart whole instance.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Something is really wrong.The heap dump doesn't make much sense either. I don't have good knowledge about web frameworks and JVM though.